# Storage in LWUIT

Tags: java-me, storage, lwuit

Please can someone give me a small sample of how to use the Storage class in LWUIT? I have tried implementing by emulating the system used in the Recipe Hands-on-Lab, but my application does not need to have multiple objects, as it is within the sample.
Recipe sample allows user to add more and more samples, but all I want to do is add ONE entry of information.

Also how do I retrieve the info stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
com.sun.lwuit.io.Storage.init("MobileApplication1");
if(com.sun.lwuit.io.Storage.isInitialized()) {
    com.sun.lwuit.io.Storage.getInstance().writeObject("MobileApplication1","My first string");
    String myStr = (String)com.sun.lwuit.io.Storage.getInstance().readObject("MobileApplication1");
    System.out.println(myStr);
} else {
    System.out.println("Storage not initialized");
}
```

The above code will create a storage of name 'MobileApplication1', add an object 'My first string' and reads the string.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks @Vimal You are a life saver. But this is for single values. What I need is for value pairs, something within LWUIT so that porting will be easier between platforms.

Comment: `Storage.writeObject(...,param2)` second parameter takes type `Object` so you can serialize the value pair object and store it. Using `Storage.readObject(...)` you read and deserialize the value pair.

Answer (score 0):

You can use J2ME record store as well and your record store will always have only 1 record.